# Running Scrapy on Dokku using a Digital Ocean server

Tags: python, heroku, scrapy, digital-ocean, dokku

Not sure how to describe this but I am running a Scrapy spider on a Digital Ocean server ($5 server), the Scrapy project is deployed as a Dokku app.

However, it runs very slowly compared to the speed on my local computer and on a Heroku free tier dyno. On Dokku it crawls at a speed of 30 pages per minute while locally and on Heroku the speed is 200+ pages per minutes.

I do not know how to debug, analyze or where to start in order to fix the problem. Any help, clues or tips on how to solve this?

Comment: You can try to enable [`AutoThrottle`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/1.1/topics/autothrottle.html). Did your spider get killed due to running out of memory?

Comment: I have already enabled AutoThrottle. It does not get killed due to running out of memory (I am using 1gb of swap memory). It may very well be a memory problem, the DO server also runs postgresql and elasticsearch while those services are ran separately on Heroku. I will test it out :) Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I tried the 10 and 20 dollar DO servers but they had the same result. Results were the same. It finally worked when running it on AWS or Linode. Don't know why, but I guess I have to switch.

Answer (score 1):

I 'fixed' this issue by not using a Digital Ocean server. The website that I am trying to crawl, which is craigslist.org, just did not respond well to a DO server. It takes a long time to respond to a request. Other websites like Google or Amazon work just fine with DO.

My scraper works just fine on craigslist when using a VPS from another provider.